# Bash array from string with nested quotations without eval

Tags: bash, eval

```bash
input="a b '1 2 3' c"

arr=($input); printf '%s|' "${arr[@]}"
# Prints: a|b|'1|2|3'|c|

eval "arr=($input)"; printf '%s|' "${arr[@]}"
# Prints: a|b|1 2 3|c|
```

How does one get the latter output without using `eval`?

Comment: `declare -a 'arr=('"$input"')'; printf '%s|' "${arr[@]}"`

Comment: @tshiono thanks! Is this vulnerable to code injection in the same way `eval` is?

Comment: `declare` is a bit less evil than `eval` but still has vulnerability. We should sanitize the input to avoid unwanted execution of malicious commands.

Answer (score 2):

bash v5.2 ships with `dsv`, a CSV parsing loadable command

```bash
$ echo "$BASH_VERSION"
5.2.15(1)-release
$ echo "$BASH_LOADABLES_PATH"
/usr/local/lib/bash       # your milage may vary here
```

Then, [enable it](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-enable) and parse that string

```bash
$ enable dsv
$ input="a b '1 2 3' c"
$ dsv -a arr -d ' ' -S "$input"
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="1 2 3" [3]="c")
```

To explain the options:

```bash
$ help dsv
dsv: dsv [-a ARRAYNAME] [-d DELIMS] [-Sgp] string
    Read delimiter-separated fields from STRING.

    Parse STRING, a line of delimiter-separated values, into individual
    fields, and store them into the indexed array ARRAYNAME starting at
    index 0. The parsing understands and skips over double-quoted strings.
    If ARRAYNAME is not supplied, "DSV" is the default array name.
    If the delimiter is a comma, the default, this parses comma-
    separated values as specified in RFC 4180.

    The -d option specifies the delimiter. The delimiter is the first
    character of the DELIMS argument. Specifying a DELIMS argument that
    contains more than one character is not supported and will produce
    unexpected results. The -S option enables shell-like quoting: double-
    quoted strings can contain backslashes preceding special characters,
    and the backslash will be removed; and single-quoted strings are
    processed as the shell would process them. The -g option enables a
    greedy split: sequences of the delimiter are skipped at the beginning
    and end of STRING, and consecutive instances of the delimiter in STRING
    do not generate empty fields. If the -p option is supplied, dsv leaves
    quote characters as part of the generated field; otherwise they are
    removed.

    The return value is 0 unless an invalid option is supplied or the ARRAYNAME
    argument is invalid or readonly.
```

Comment: There is also a `csv` loadable command, but it's hardcoded to split on comma.